# Showing an entire function is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Suppose $f$ is an entire function with the property that

$|f(z)|\leq C\exp(|z|^\rho)$ with $\rho\geq0$. And $f(\log(n))=0 \forall n\geq3 $

Now I have to prove that $f$ is identically $0$.

I was thinking that if $f$ could be shown to be uniformly bounded then by Liouville's theorem we'd have that it is identically $0$.But I couldn't see how to use $f(\log(n))=0$.

Can someone please  help me solve this ? Note that this is a problem from the chapter Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: Any conditions on $\rho$?

Comment: The condition given says that $f$ is of finite order at most $\rho$, so (unless $f$ identically zero) there is a bound of its number of zeroes in a large disc of radius $R$, namely $CR^{\rho}$ for some fixed $C>0$ and all large $R$; the condition on the zeroes though gives about $e^R$ zeroes there and that is a contradiction for large $R$

Comment: yeah $\rho\geq0$. I've edited it.

Comment: @conrad is it possible to do this without using Jensen's formula?The proof of the fact you stated requires that , right?

Comment: Yes, one usually uses Jensen formula; not sure what you mean "without" Jensen as of course one can recover the result directly (assume $f$ nonzero, let $R$ st there is no zero on the circle of radius $R$, take the $n(R)$ zeroes inside the disc of radius $R$, take them out with $B_R$ the usual Blaschke product, then $\log |f/B|$ is harmonic in the disc, so by the mean value theorem one has that the integral on the circle of that is $2\pi \log |f/B|(0)$ and then on one hand estimate $\log |f|$ superior by the hypothesis with $\rho$, on the other hand evaluate $-\int_{|z|=R}\log |B|$ directly etc

Comment: actually $-\int_{|z|=R}\log |B|=0$ since $|B|=1$ there but $\log |f/B|(0)|$ gives you the inferior estimate required (more or less $e^R$) since all the terms in $-\log |B(0)|$ are positive and there are at least $n(R) \ge e^R$ of them, while the integral on the circle of $\log |f|$ is at most of size $R^{\rho}$, so the equality of the two is incompatible for large enough $R$